# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there guys and gals,

I am currently working with `MAMP` however, it's broken and I can't seem to find a way to fix it. The last time I used it it was working fine, when it came to finishing up for the day I stopped the servers properly, and shut down `MAMP` rather than just shutting down the `Mac` and leaving it to close everything itself,  the next day I started `MAMP` and tried to start the `servers` but the `MySQL` server will refuse to start however, the `Apache server` does start; this is becoming a real issue for me.

If anyone could help I would be highly grateful.

Thanks,

Tijger.